# How can I turn the ACT LED off on Pi 3

Tags: pi-3, raspbian-stretch

Is here any way i can turn off the ACT led on my Pi 3?
I am using it in a situation where the light of the LED will mess up some of my results.
I am running Raspbian Stretch.

I will greatly appreciate any help given! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Stick a piece of black tape over the LED or

The following command disables the activity LED on the Pi3.

`echo none > /sys/class/leds/led0/trigger`

That says nothing should trigger the activity LED.

The following command shows the other choices.

`cat /sys/class/leds/led0/trigger`

> none kbd-scrollock kbd-numlock kbd-capslock kbd-kanalock kbd-shiftlock
>   kbd-altgrlock kbd-ctrllock kbd-altlock kbd-shiftllock kbd-shiftrlock
>   kbd-ctrlllock kbd-ctrlrlock [mmc0] mmc1 timer oneshot heartbeat
>   backlight gpio cpu0 cpu1 cpu2 cpu3 default-on input rfkill0 rfkill1

Comment: Is it possible to turn the power led off?

Answer (score 0):

I find the default setting of the `ACT` LED useless, and change it to heartbeat by including `dtparam=act_led_trigger=heartbeat` in `config.txt`.

You should be able to use any of the trigger values, including `none`.

I have found using `/sys/class/leds/` directly unreliable, although it does work for `ACT` but not `PWR`

Answer (score -2):

Turn off the power LED using this command in the terminal:

```
echo 0 > /sys/class/leds/led1/brightness
```

Comment: your inclusion of the command prompt makes the pertinent information very hard to see. Also, have you read the other answers which not only contain the same info but mention that it is not always effective?